# Adding dictionary security inside a generalized function (.Net Framework 4.8)

Tags: c#

I have this function call

```
FunctionName( List, s => new Class(s,Dictionary[s.Key]));
```

Inside the FunctionName

```
private void FunctionName<T>(List<T> Data, Func<KeyValuePair<string, object>,T>)
        {
              foreach (... entry in ...)
              {
                  Data.Add(ClassCreator(entry));
              }
            
            return;
        }
```

The problem is, because FunctionName is generic i cannot add a dictionary checking in case of KeyNotFoundException because it could be other type of variable all along.

Is it possible to add that verification in the function calling?

Something like:

```
if(KeyNotFoundException) {string.Empty}
else{Dictionary[...]}
```

Answer

```
FunctionName(
List, 
object value;
if (Dictionary.TryGetValue(s.Key, out value)) {
     FunctionName(s => new Class(s, value)); 
} 
else {     
     FunctionName(s => new Class(s, string.Empty)); }
);
```

Comment: what about doing like this ? `object value;
if (Dictionary.TryGetValue(s.Key, out value))
{
    FunctionName(s => new Class(s, value));
}
else
{
    FunctionName(s => new Class(s, string.Empty));
}` or have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: The real code has a lot of things and is extremely unclear

Comment: @viveknuna inside the function calling?

Comment: @Filipe yes, whats the problem with it?

Comment: didn't notice i could do it just like that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the checking in the lambda:

```
F(s => new Class(s, dict.TryGetValue(s.Key, out var x) ? x : string.Empty));
```